# Mobile Webapps Alerting Users

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, alert

Is there anyway to have an audible alert on an android/iphone webapp?
Would like to alert the user when an event occurs.

Comment: How is it coded? Is this pure web? Do you use android webview? Any js framework? Isn't a visual alert enough?

Comment: I'm using JSF&GWT but my question is more general as to whether it is possible to make audible alerts. Visual alert probably wont be enough unless it will activate a screen from screensaver mode (i.e. similar to a text/phone call when on silent).

Answer (score 0):

On android, you can execute java code from javascript, but you need to [run your webapp in a WebView](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html).

If your webapp runs in a bare browser, you could also check for the html5 audio api, might do the trick.